# buffer-local values for SQL query parameters

Tags: sql, emacs

Using `sql-send-buffer`, I can send a SQL query from a file to an open SQL REPL.  Many of my queries have parameter placeholders (in Postgres syntax, `$1`, `$2` &c.) . Does anyone have code analogous to `sql-send-buffer` that will prompt for values to fill in for these parameters?  Ideally, I'd like it to store the values I provide, and not prompt again unless I add parameters or close the file.

Currently I either:

1. replace the parameters in the file, try to remember not to commit or deploy these test values (error prone)
2. copy the query into the REPL, replace parameters there (tedious)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```lisp
(defvar my-sql-replacements nil)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-sql-replacements)

(defun my-sql-send-buffer-replace ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((string (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
    (while (string-match "[$][0-9]" string)
      (let* ((placeholder (match-string 0 string))
             (replacement (or (cdr (assoc placeholder my-sql-replacements))
                              (read-string (format "Replacement for %s: " placeholder)))))
        (unless (assoc placeholder my-sql-replacements)
          (push (cons placeholder replacement) my-sql-replacements))
        (setq string (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote placeholder) replacement string))))
    (sql-send-string string)))
```

I haven't tested it with an actual SQL server, but from tracing `sql-send-string` it looks like it should work.  It stores the replacements in a buffer-local variable.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great.  I made one small change to the regex `[$][0-9]+` to handle queries with more than 9 parameters.